# Vue.js different notations

Tags: vue.js

What notation/style/something else does a Vue.js documentation use? It looks like this:

[image]

It has ***var vm = new Vue({*** before it
While my Vue looks differently something like this:

```
<template>
  <router-link class="element" :to="{name: 'Home', params: {id: id}}">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    
    <div class="operation-type">
      <span class="access-type">{{accesstype}}</span>
      <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'WriteElement',
  props: {
    write: Object,
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.element {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

I installed Vue through Vue CLI (and it comes with bunch of instruments that I have no idea what they do)

Comment: That code you're seeing is the initialization of a new VueJS application. The Vue code you're seeing is the code of a Vue component exported as an ES6 module.

Comment: @Terry why don't they make documentation examples using components?

Comment: They do? See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html. Also in your case, you are exporting a [Vue component as a SFC](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns) so that it can be imported elsewhere: a more advanced use-case of Vue components.

Comment: @Terry so there are 3 types of using Vue? new Vue({}), Vue.component and SFC using webpack?

Comment: No. `new Vue()` is the one and only way to initialize a VueJS app. For VueCLI you will see that code in `main.js` (or whatever entry file there is). A VueJS app may contain one or more components: those can be initialized using `Vue.component` or by importing SFC.